# C# Initialize object with parallel task or some other way

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class constructor with something like:

```
AuthenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
```

However this "variable initialization" may take some seconds and sometimes the father class may still not need it.
How can I use parallel programming in order to initialize it and still let the "father" class continue and only wait when he needs to use it and the object AuthenticationService is still not ready.

How can I do this?

**My Solution (thanks to Jon Skeet)**

```
    private Task<AuthenticationService> authTask;
    public AuthenticationService AuthenticationService
    {
        get
        {
            return authTask.Result;
        }
    }

    public MyConstructor(){
          authTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new AuthenticationService());
    }
```

Comment: Seem you could use Lazy<T>, that will calc values when they are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Task`:

```
Task<AuthenticationService> authTask = 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new AuthenticationService);

// Do other things here...

// Now if we *really* need it, block until we've got it.
AuthenticationService authService = authTask.Result;
```

Note that the `Result` property will block the current thread until the result is available. If you were using C# 5, you might want to consider using an asynchronous method instead, in which case you could `await` the task.

Comment: Check my implementation. Thanks

Comment: @Dryadwoods: Why bother with the separate variable? Just return `authTask.Result` every time. Although I would make it a method rather than a property, given that it could take a while to return.